# In $\Bbb Z[x,y]$ is $(x^2+1,y^2+1,-xy+1)$ prime?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes

This is a reality check for the following computations that I did:

Consider the map $(\operatorname{id}, \iota): \Bbb A_\Bbb Z^1 \rightarrow \Bbb A_\Bbb Z^1\times \Bbb A_\Bbb Z^1$ from the definition of a group scheme. In the coordinate rings it is given by $$\Bbb Z[t] \otimes \Bbb Z[t] \cong \Bbb Z [x,y]\rightarrow \Bbb Z[t]\\ x \mapsto t\\y\mapsto -t.$$

I'm trying to find the preimage of the prime ideal $(t^2+1) \subset \Bbb Z[t]$. It contains $(x^2+1, y^2+1, -xy+1)$. Is that all?

**Aside:** I complexified everything to have a more geometric picture and I found that the image of the closed set $I=V(t^2+1)$ under this map is $\{(\pm i, \mp i)\}$, which is also closed. This brought me the side question: when should I expect the image of closed sets to be closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(x^2+1,y^2+1,xy-1)$ we see that $x=x(xy)=x^2 y = -y$. It follows immediately that $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(x^2+1,y^2+1,xy-1) \to \mathbb{Z}[t]/(t^2+1)$, $x \mapsto t$, $y \mapsto -t$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Hm... This answers the question. But what about the preimage of $(t^2+t+1)$? I can find that it must contain $(x^2+x+1,x^2-y+1,-xy+y+1,-xy-y+1, y^2+x+1, y^2-y+1)$. But is it all?

Comment: This is a new question.

Comment: Well, I liked your answer, but that's because I wasn't expecting something adhoc. I was wondering if the solution would involve Gröbner basis.